# Has R&D explained how super-powerful cards like Oko and Uro were printed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

These past few years, there've been several ridiculously powerful cards printed in Standard that eventually got banned in Modern or even Legacy (!). [Oko, Thief of Crowns](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oko%2C%20Thief%20of%20Crowns) and [Uro, Titan of Nature's Wrath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Uro%2C%20Titan%20of%20Nature%27s%20Wrath) are the biggest offenders. The two cards being in the same colors led to a Pro Tour where most players maindecked four copies of [Noxious Grasp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Noxious%20Grasp). [Field of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Field%20of%20the%20Dead) and [Once Upon a Time](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Once%20Upon%20a%20Time) are also in the same league.

Has R&D ever explained how these cards made it through the testing process? I know they did for [Skullclamp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skullclamp) (mentioned [in this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/4282)) and also [Felidar Guardian](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Felidar%20Guardian) (mentioned in [this MTG Goldfish article](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/articles/future-future-league-failures-and-fixes); the link there is dead but can be found at the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220811001216/https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/latest-developments/m-files-aether-revolt-part-1-2017-02-03)), and I'm looking for something similar for these or other Standard-banned cards.

Comment: Have a look at the rarity of the cards in question. That's why.

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim Oko and Uro were so far beyond the power of even any other Mythic Rares. Getting banned in Legacy is quite a feat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark Rosewater, the lead designer on Magic: the Gathering recently answered [a related question](https://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/718677607944749056/banning-cards-is-necessary-but-its-always-a-sign) on his Tumblr blog about the overall design philosophy that results in overpowered cards:

> Question:
>
> > Banning cards is necessary but it's always a sign that something went wrong. I'd like to suggest a post/article about lessons learned from bannings. For instance, what was the goal/story of Fable of the mirror break design, what/why it went wrong and what's the lesson learned.
>
> Answer:
>
> > Cards being banned aren’t always a sign that things went wrong. We could make a world where cards never (or almost never) get banned by never pushing boundaries, but we don’t think that would be as fun of a game.
> >
> > I truly believe if nothing ever gets banned, we aren’t doing or job properly. We’re supposed to come up to the line, which occasionally means we step over it, as where exactly the line is changes based on so many conditions.

---

There is a [play design article](https://magic.wizards.com/en/news/feature/play-design-lessons-learned-2019-11-18) that addresses what happened with Oko in particular:

> Alongside power level, we were working on different structures for the Food deck, moving planeswalkers around on the mana curve to react to shifting costs elsewhere in the file, and churning through a variety of designs to try and find something that had any hope of being a fun Constructed card. Earlier versions of Oko had most of their power tied up in (a much broader) stealing ability, which was even less fun for the opponent than turning them into Elk.
>
> Ultimately, we did not properly respect his ability to invalidate essentially all relevant permanent types, and over the course of a slew of late redesigns, we lost sight of the sheer, raw power of the card, and overshot it by no small margin.

Comment: This is a very nice collection of statements. Judging by these snippets alone, it would allow for the assumption that cards are being designed with a margin for overpoweredness in mind, which would then possibly be fixed by banning cards in focus formats such as Standard or Modern. If that were the case, this means that other formats such as Commander (which isn't very trigger-happy at all as far as bans are concerned) will still have to deal with those cards. I'm not sure how great such a strategy is, especially considering that someone *really* should have caught Oko's general utility...

Comment: @TheThirdMan At least years back (when I was still actively playing MtG) the official WotC stance was always that they design and test cards primarily for Standard. How defensible that policy is given that Standard has long stopped being the "standard" way how most players interact with the game is a different question - but so is whether it's even possible to continuously print interesting cards without them ever breaking one of n formats. I believe that's also what Rosewater alludes to.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Also, there is the historical perspective that WotC has learned the hard way that underpowered sets are financially substantially worse for them than overpowered ones. I believe this line of thinking is what ultimately led us to the Age of Oko.

Comment: @xLeitix I'm sure that Standard is more of a measure than Commander or other formats. However, since Commander sets are produced by WotC by the many, they shouldn't completely disregard its existance either. My point wasn't and isn't to tell them what to do though, and I do see your points of course - but when they are banning cards, they confirm there's a limit to how powerful a card should get - and while I can understand missing Saheeli - but only recognizing Oko's power level after the fact (even just looking at Standard) isn't very reassuring of their dedication to balancing in my opinion

Comment: @TheThirdMan Sure, and they said they messed up. I have been following MtG since the early days, this isn't the first nor will it be the last massive balance cockup (Skullclamp was a fun and similar one, where it simply never crossed their mind that giving a creature -1 actually made it an engine by itself).

Comment: @TheThirdMan Personally, I am less concerned about individual crazy cards like Oko that they simply missed. What bothers me more is the tendency to print sets like War of the Spark, where clearly the design goal behind the entire set was to have a crazy power level. Such sets don't happen by accident, somebody decided that they want a set that roughs up every format.

Comment: @xLeitix Agreed... my concern also isn't with single cards that a person missed who tried their best but honestly missed it - my concern is that presumably for profit-before-balancing reasons. the integrity of the game as a whole (read: a large number of feeling-of-the-game-changing set releases), or at least such a change for the Commander and other eternal formats. Single cards being as blown-out-of-proportions as Oko is are simply alarmingly indicative of such changes, in my opinion.